# Return en una funcion

Tags: python

Estoy creando una función para que retorne `1` cuando el primer numero es mayor que el segundo, `-1` si el segundo numero es mayor que el primero y `0` si ambos son iguales
sin embargo cuando introduzco los números no me imprime nada en pantalla

```
numero1=int(input("inserte numero 1: "))
numero2=int(input("inserte numero 2: "))

def relacion(a=numero1,b=numero2):
    if numero1 > numero2:
        print(1)
    elif numero1 < numero2:
        print(-1)
    else:
        print(0)

  relacion(numero1,numero2)
```

alguien podria ilustrarme mejor como funciona el return y cual es la diferencia entre return y print() o son iguales? he leido en algunos sitios que actuan igual pero la verdad estoy un poco confundida

Comment: será por que debes usar las variables `a` y `b` en vez de `numero1` y `numero2`?? o quizás por que has indentado mal la llamada a la función?

Comment: La indentación es importante en python porque define que cosas están adentro de una función y que cosas estan afuera.

Answer (score 0):

> lo compile y el error es de IndentationError con subir un renglón se
> soluciona
>
> en online --->programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/
>
> con esta identacion pide los numeros y los imprime sin problemas

```
numero1=int(input("inserte numero 1: "))
numero2=int(input("inserte numero 2: "))

def relacion(a=numero1,b=numero2):
    if numero1 > numero2:
        print(1)
    elif numero1 < numero2:
        print(-1)
    else:
        print(0)
relacion(numero1,numero2)
```

> En esta otra online sin modificar nada no da error tu codigo

[compilacion online python](https://www.online-python.com/)

> La diferencia entre print() y return aunque ese no era el problema por
> el cual no  imprimia
> print() es una funcion incorparada sirve para mostrar un mensaje en
> pantalla en cambio return es una palabra reservada que establece el
> valor de retorno de una funcion

```
def relacion(numero1,numero2):
        if numero1 > numero2:
            print(1)
            return 1
        elif numero1 < numero2:
            print(-1)
            return -1
        else:
            print(0)
            return 0
    a=relacion(10,5)
    print(a)
```

Por ejemplo forma correcta

```
def numero_maximo(a, b):
    if a > b:
        maximo = a
    else:
        maximo = b
    return maximo
```

> forma incorrecta numero_maximo_print()

```
def numero_maximo_print(a, b):
    if a > b:
        maximo = a
    else:
        maximo = b
    print(maximo)  # Reemplazamos el return
```

Comment: Deberías ampliar tu pregunta para aclarar la confusión que tiene respecto a la declaración `def relacion(a=numero1, b=numero2)`.

Comment: pero un  valor de retorno no seria como imprimir algo? esa es mi confusion @nestdan

Answer (score 0):

En **C** se distingue entre procedimientos y funciones.

- En los **procedimientos** se le envía unos datos y realiza unas instrucciones no devolviendo ningún dato (sería el caso que tú planteas).
- En las **funciones** se le envían los datos, realiza unas instrucciones y devuelve un valor(para ello utiliza el return) con el que luego podrás realizar operaciones, imprimir, etc.

Los datos los va recogiendo en el orden en que se los envía y podemos (se recomienda hacerlo) cambiar el nombre a las variables .

Podríamos crear una función de este estilo:

```
def mayor(a, b):
    if a > b:
        return 1
    if a < b:
        return -1
    return 0
```

La función devuelve el dato y no sigue ejecutándose.

El resto del programa:

```
numero1=int(input("inserte numero 1: "))
numero2=int(input("inserte numero 2: "))
resultado = mayor(numero1, numero2) # Llamada a la función y recoges el valor
print(resultado) # Haces algo con el valor
```

En **python** la función podría quedar así:

```
def mayor(a,b):
    return 1 if a > b else -1 if a < b else 0
```

En algunos casos se puede preferir plantear un valor por defecto.
La gran ventaja de las funciones es que se pueden reutilizar. En otra parte del programa hay que comprobar si el dato es mayor que 0, con lo que puedes hacerlo así:

```
def mayor(a,b=0):
    return 1 if a > b else  -1 if a > b else 0

numero1=int(input("inserte numero 1: "))
print(mayor(numero1))
```

La misma función comparará si el valor es mayor que 0.
No sé si esa es la causa de como defines la función

```
def relacion(a=numero1,b=numero2):
```

en vez de

```
def mayor(a,b):
```